# spin article, based on condition (not random)

Tags: php

I found some code here for spinning.

Tried to add **if/else**. But could not get it to work as described below.

What I want to do is; depending on the value of the $dom, change some part of the text. On this example; if "**dom=com**" link is clicked, the text should be "is this the domain **.com** ?" if not then "is this the domain **.us** ?"
And the reason that I wanted to do it this way is;
I am planning to use this piece of code for a few parked domains so some part of the texts will be different.

```
    <h1><a href="/test.php?dom=com">com</a> | <a href="/test.php?dom=us">us</a></h1>
    <?

    $dom = $_GET['dom'];

    function spin($var){
    $words = explode("{",$var);
    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        $words = explode("}",$word);
        foreach ($words as $word)
        {
            $words = explode("|",$word);
    if ($dom = "com"){$word = $words[0];}
    else {$word = $words[1];}
    echo $word." ";
        }
    }
    }
$text = "<font size=\"6\">is this the domain {<b>.com</b> |<b>.us</b> } ?, so you are from {anywhere|usa} ?</font><br />";
    spin($text);
    ?>
```

Comment: Remember to sanitise the data before you output it.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("<font size=\"6\">is this the domain <b>%s</b> ?</font><br />",$_GET['dom']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Who knows what the function is for...

```
<?php
    $dom = $_GET["dom"];
    echo "Is this the domain.".$dom."?";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but, as I have tried to explain above, this code is to spin alot larger text, actually a .htm file where there will be alot more of {we|you} / {100|hundred}vs vs vs. So its not this.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "spin"

Comment: Article spinners ? creates random text variations. I just want to have a fixed one.. if condition 1, then choose the first one in {100|hundred} , if not choose the second one.